# how to correctly configure nvidia GT-520MX on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, bumblebee

I'm trying to be able ubuntu graphical effects and unity 3D with the video card in the title on my samsung np300e5a. They seem to run fine with a live cd or usb but they don't on a fresh install.

I initially didn't know that the video card actually was a double one (integrated intel+dedicated nvidia) with OPTIMUS technology, and Bumblebee was the official tool to make it work, so I installed the official sh script downloaded from the nvidia website. It didn't work, so I uninstalled it.

I tried to install bumblebee, but the result was a unbootable system. The only way to start it (without the graphics) is to run recovery mode and resume normal boot. When I try to run startx I get the error "fatal server error: no screens found".

Is there a way to to make my video card work properly on my ubuntu 12.04.2 (with graphical effects and 3D acceleration when needed)? I searched thoroughly the web and seems that other people with my same hardware can make it work, but for some reason, I can't...

if further infos or details about my system configuration or done operations are needed, I'm up to complete the description.

Comment: can anybody help me or suggest an already answered question that can fit my problem? I browsed over several ones, but no one seems to work for me :(

Comment: I have provided an extensive answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/which-driver-should-i-install-when-using-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card

But I would recommend reading first this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108648/bumblebee-or-ironhide

Comment: Thank you so much Luis! Your tutorial was perfect and now it seems I have correctly configured my nvidia video card. I did the followsing steps:
- removal of nvidia binary drivers
- removal of nvidia-current and nvidia-current-updates packages
- removal of /etc/X11/xorg.conf file
- installation of xserver-xorg-video-nouveau open source drivers
...and it worked! 
I suppose that my nvidia GPU is now correctly running because I had previously installed bumblebee packages on my system. Am I right?

Comment: I will update the source answer to include a part about bumblebee usage to avoid this kind of problems. But I am glad everything worked out.